# My soundscape archives are getting messy. Any database structure/metadata recommendations?

Tags: soundscape, archive, bigdata

I face big data archives of field recordings collected with Autonomous Recording Units (ARUs) and I am wondering of some standard database structure that I should respect. Any reports or papers you could recommend?

Comment: Are you looking for organizational advice for the audio files or the metadata related to the deployments (e.g. sample rate, lat/long, time period of recording, instrument details etc)?

Comment: yes that would be great

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could look to public soundscape archival entities for inspiration. For example, [NOAA National Centers for Environmental Information (NCEI) has a Passive Acoustic Data map](https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/maps/passive_acoustic_data/). If you click on points on this map, you can eventually click through to a JSON file that shows the structure of the key-values used in their database and archival system ([example here](https://storage.googleapis.com/noaa-passive-bioacoustic/adeon/hat/amar.381.4/metadata/adeon_en626_hat.amar381.4-metadata.json)).

Depending on how large and collaborative your project is, you might have different needs out of a database / organizational system. In the past, I have worked on projects where we organized the data in SQLite, which is a fairly lightweight and flexible system. Pros: you don't need a database administrator -- you can do it yourself! Cons: a lack of "concurrency" if you are going to have many contributors to the database (though not typically an issue if you or a small number of collaborators are the only ones contributing to the database).

For R users, it is possible to set up a SQLite database from R and manage your data via R packages such as RSQLite and DBI. [Here is a paper on how some colleagues and I have made this work for prior acoustic monitoring projects](https://besjournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/2041-210X.13397) as well as a [Gitlab Wiki page on the database structure we used](https://code.usgs.gov/vtcfwru/ammonitor) (all code is available at this repository). This particular software is undergoing some changes, however -- suffice to say, it is quite an undertaking to elegantly manage a large set of acoustics data, and to have the foresight to figure out all the pieces you need to track and how they should relate together.

Comment: Hi, the link to your gitlab wiki is not working. could you update it? many thanks :)

Comment: I found it: https://code.usgs.gov/vtcfwru/ammonitor

Comment: Thanks @Amandine Gasc. I've edited to fix the link!

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if you're more interested in data/metadata standards themselves or platforms for which to archive recordings, but if it's the latter, here are some -

[ARBIMON](https://arbimon.rfcx.org/) (from Rainforest Connection) is a free, web-based platform for storing, managing, archiving, etc. passive acoustic recordings. Also has functionality for spectrogram viewing, template matching, etc.

There is also [Biosounds](https://github.com/nperezg/biosounds), a web-based platform for ecoacoustics that archives and organises soundscape collections.